# How to avoid mutation of the object in thunks

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I want to create a new `object` each time my action is called. I have now achived this by using `Object.assign`, but is there a better way to achive this because `Object.assign` is not a deep copy?

```
export const addPlayer: Thunk = (players: any[], name: string) => (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  const state = Object.assign({}, getState().players);
  errors.forEach(e => {
    state.playerQueue.push({
      player: {
        message: e.message,
        name
      }
    });
  });
  dispatch(playersAction(state));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));`. This is not the best way but you can get the deep copy of an object. Works well for small objects.

Comment: Thanks, I also found the npm package `clone` to work well for this issue now.